# Enumerating the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

The elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ can be enumerated as $0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, \ldots$. Similarly, the points of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ can be enumerated

$$(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1), (2,0), (1,1), (0,2), (-1,1), \ldots$$

I would like to extend this algorithm to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Is there a simple way to do that?

Note that the ordering of the elements may vary. The only condition should be that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are two closed balls in the metric $L^1$ on $\mathbb{Z}^n$, and $B_1 \subset B_2$, then all the elements of $B_1$ should be enumerated before any element of $B_2 - B_1$.

Comment: I don't see how the subset condition can be satisfied.  Do you mean all elements of $B_1$ are enumerated before any elements of $B_2-B_1$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will correct it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\Bbb Z^n$ = $\bigcup B(0, k)$ (closed ball for the $L^1$ distance in $\Bbb Z^n$).

Then enumerate the elements of $B(0, k) - B(0, k-1)$ in lexicographic order (or reverse lexicographic order in you case).

Then you get an enumeration with the property you asked for, generalizing you enumeration in the case $n=2$ to the general case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, that's a bit too general, and a bit obvious too. Could you be more specific? For instance, how can you get the points in $B(0,k) - B(0,k-1)$?

Comment: $B(0,k) - B(0,k-1) = \{u: \sum |u_i| = k\}$, and then you can get them easily via recursion, from the ball in $Z^{n-1}$.